# Some basic non-inverting op-amp circuit questions

Tags: operational-amplifier

In this circuit diagram [from Electronics-tutorials.ws](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_3.html) what might be the meaning of the line from 0v to the unconnected arrow up to Vout on the right?

[image: non-inverting operational amplifier]

I have found lots of higher level explanations of how to use op-amps but the most basic stuff is left out. So I have to ask how do I get the amp to output a range from 0 to 9v? is it just by supplying it with 9v? I am using a ADA4522-1 [Farnell](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/3757612.pdf)
In that case how do I know what should be the resistance of one of the resisters R1(Rf) and R2 to be able to calculate the resistance of the other?
This other circuit diagram which I am a bit unsure about is the power supply for the accelerometer, op-amp and PLC, does that look ok to expert eyes? Any comment much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Why not start by telling us what your input device is and where its datasheet can be found? Then tell us what you expect to do with it and what will be receiving the final output? Everything is about the input source and its requirements and the output destination and its requirements. Sample rates may be important, too. Finally, what power supply rails you have available. The stuff otherwise in between is mostly determined then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *how do I get the amp to output a range from 0 to 9v? is it just by
> supplying it with 9v? I am using a ADA4522-1*

That op-amp is really good but, as with any rail-to-rail output op-amp, it can't quite reach an output voltage of 9 volts when the positive supply is fixed at 9 volts. You might get to within 30 mV of 9 volts so, I would recommend using a 10 volt supply to achieve a 9 volt output.

Remember also that this applies to the op-amp being able to reach 0 volts; there will be a limit to how low the output can go i.e. although the op-amp is described as output rail-to-rail, it's a small fib.

> *how do I know what should be the resistance of one of the resisters
> R1(Rf) and R2 to be able to calculate the resistance of the other?*

As with most op-amps of this type, it is usual to nominally choose a feedback resistor (Rf/R1) of around 10 kΩ. But this could be from 1 kΩ to 100 kΩ. From the you can calculate R2 using the gain equation.

> *This other circuit diagram which I am a bit unsure about is the power
> supply for the accelerometer, op-amp and PLC, does that look ok to
> expert eyes? Any comment much appreciated.*

It doesn't have any obvious errors. It has omissions such as a localized power supply decoupling capacitor for the op-amp and maybe, you could add a series resistor of maybe 1 kΩ in the feed to the PLC. The accelerator IC might have some special requirements such as supply decoupling and output load resistor but, that cannot be determined by your information.

> *what might be the meaning of the line from 0v to the unconnected arrow
> up to Vout on the right?*

Does this help: -

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of the line from 0V to Vout, represents the the polarity of the

output voltage. Please see the image below.The arrow is anaother way of representing + and - in

circuit analysis.Arrow head represents positive and start represent negative.

[image]

Arrow define the voltage direction.

[image]

Comment: The output could be negative as well, the arrows indicate that the output polarity follows the input polarity, it’s relative not absolute.